# Ending a thread safely when using UDP Receive

Tags: c#, multithreading, udp

I'm creating a thread that runs a UDP Client that receives a message, after it receives the message I want to close the UDP client and then end the thread, but I dont know how to end the thread since "Receive" always runs until it gets an answer.

This is my code so far:

```
private void RecieveChallenge()
{
    UdpClient client = new UdpClient(26000);
    IPEndPoint remoteIp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

    Byte[] receivedBytes = client.Receive(ref remoteIp);
    string ipAddress = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedBytes);
}
```

The important line is client.Receive(ref remoteIp);

Here is how I start my thread:

```
Thread recieveChallengeThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RecieveChallenge));
recieveDataThread.Start();
```

Comment: So ais the question that you want it to time out? Otherwise once it receives the data, the thread will exit cleanly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`client.Receive` will return an empty `byte[]` when the connection is closed. You should just have to close the connection and change the provided code to:

```
private void RecieveChallenge()
{
    UdpClient client = new UdpClient(26000);
    IPEndPoint remoteIp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

    Byte[] receivedBytes = client.Receive(ref remoteIp);
    if (receivedBytes == null || receivedBytes.Length == 0)
        return;
    string ipAddress = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedBytes);
}
```

Though you'll probably want `RecieveChallenge` to return a boolean indicating whether it is closed or not (of course ignoring the fact that your thread will only ever receive one message).

Comment: Where does it say it will return null? A SocketException or ObjectDisposedException will be thrown if it is closed while attempting to receive.

Comment: @Brad - That would be true if you attempt to read from an already disposed socket (while it is disposed), though if you're already waiting for a response I think it'll actually return an empty `byte[]`. I know this is true for the underlying `Socket` class at least.

Comment: @M.Babcok I'm almost positive it will thrown an exception as it blocks until it receives data. Therefore the thread will run unless you kill the thread or the socket, which will then thrown an exception.

Comment: This is not safe. There is no guarantee that it is safe to close the endpoint in one thread while another endpoint is about to use it. (At least, none that I know of.)

Comment: @Brad - As I said in my previous comment I know this works this way in the underlying `Socket` class. I cannot comment directly on the behavior of the `UDPClient`. You could be right though.

Comment: @M.Babcock UdpClient is just a wrapper around the Socket. This is based on the Reference Source (http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - I've used this several times in various in production applications using the `Socket` class with success. I cannot directly comment on the `UDPClient`'s behavior though. If you have a safer alternative, please feel free to share.

Comment: @Brad - I'm aware of how the hierarchy works. That doesn't mean the behavior in this situation would be different though.

Comment: There are plenty of other ways. One simple way is to set a "shutdown" flag that the thread checks after every successful call to receive. Then you set the shutdown flag and send a UDP datagram to yourself. (That it works successfully when you tried it is meaningless. It could fail on the next version of the compiler, operating system, TCP/IP library, or even CPU for all we know. "It happened to work when I tested it" tells us little about the code's correctness or reliability.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - I meant to propose them to the OP. Feel free to take the answer if you have a better one.

Comment: Although I suggested BeginReceive/EndReceive in my answer, I must say that this M.Babcock's solution seems correct to me. +1 Underlying socket object can be accessed from other threads anytime, so it is legal to close it from another thread, and that will in fact force the stuck Receive method to finish. And this approach is clean.

Comment: This code is working fine, the only problem I see is that if I dont recive a message the thread will still continue to run even though I closed my program.

How would I go about that if I don't receive a message?

Comment: @Dumpen - You have a couple different options. The dirty way (which won't kill your thread gracefully) would be to set the thread as a foreground thread (`Thread.IsBackground = false`) or the cleaner way, put the `Receive` in a loop and add a receive timeout (`.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, 5000);`). You'll also need to add a try/catch around the `Receive` to catch the timeout exception if you go with the clean way. Here's a thread on it: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/51e3fb86-f0ec-4c6e-886e-ae2ac39c5997/

Comment: @M.Babcock So something like this? http://pastebin.com/SFwq7JCU (Sorry for the pastebin link, but there is a lot of code)

Comment: @Dumpen - Not exactly. Returning from the catch will cause the thread to return after the first spurt of inactivity (when no messages are received). You'll want to change that to a `continue` (or just do nothing in the catch at all - same effect). Then instead of the *evil* `while(true)` you'll want to check a flag that should only be set to `true` when the program is closing.

Comment: @Dumpen - That's much better, but there are still a couple potential flaws. Here's your code again with some commented suggestions: http://pastebin.com/M7jJKL3n

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `Receive()`, you can use `BeginReceive()`/`EndReceive()` - it is an asynchronous alternative.

See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.beginreceive.aspx

These methods use a common APM (asynchronous programming model) of .NET.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wait for it to end before continue on your current thread, you can use

```
recieveDataThread.Join();
```

Otherwise, thread closes as soon as the last line completes.

If you want to end it early, you can use

```
recieveDataThread.Abort();
```

from another thread.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for good answer and thanks to colleague advice I made following solution (seems to work fine)

```
while (_monitoringThreadIsRunning)
{                        
   var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(ReceiveTimeout);
   var receiveTask = _udpClient.ReceiveAsync();

   if (timeoutTask == await Task.WhenAny(timeoutTask, receiveTask))
      continue;

   UdpReceiveResult udpReceiveResult = await receiveTask;
   // handle udpReceiveResult.Buffer
}
```

For stopping you need to set _monitoringThreadIsRunning to false. It works without any exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

An improvement on Jacek's above solution uses a second while loop; doing so a time-out does not throw away a possible datagram that was being received at the moment a time-out fires (the original code calls for another ReceiveAsync on every time-out ignoring any ongoing Receive):

```
while (_monitoringThreadIsRunning {        
    var receiveTask = _udpClient.ReceiveAsync();                
    while (_monitoringThreadIsRunning {        
        var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(ReceiveTimeout);
        if (timeoutTask == await Task.WhenAny(timeoutTask, receiveTask))
            continue;
        UdpReceiveResult udpReceiveResult = await receiveTask;
        // handle udpReceiveResult.Buffer
        break; // return to outer loop, launching another Receive
    }
}
```

PS: I would have put this in a comment, however as it is my first contribution here, I was lacking the necessary reputation points to do so.